# How do I give users to a group access to my GCP project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I am trying to set up access control using google groups instead since our team is getting larger. I have created a group in Google group admin and added given that group access to our GCP project, but the members of the group doesn't see the GCP project in the list of available groups.

Am I missing something?

According to the doc: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview it should be possible to do exactly what I am doing.

Answer (score -3):

Reference:
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview
[enter link description here](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/33343?hl=en)

We can create Group in google account through administrator account

Comment: The questioner has already noted that he created a group in admin. Your answer doesn’t help to resolve his question.