# How to add "Google group" for Cloud IAM

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In a `Google Cloud IAM Overview` document, There is a word "Google group".

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview

```
Concepts related to identity

In Cloud IAM, you grant access to members. Members can be of following types:

Google account
Service account
Google group
G Suite domain
Cloud Identity domain
```

But How can I create "Google Group" 
I can't find something in my google cloud console for IAM.

This is duplicates of following question which has no answer.

[How do I give users to a group access to my GCP project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47750144/how-do-i-give-users-to-a-group-access-to-my-gcp-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a group for your organization in the GSuite admin console, or if you're not a GSuite customer, you can create a group at https://googlegroups.com.

-Rob